# Update Metadata Property of an Attribute in CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

Can I update IsValidForAdvancedFind property for an attribute in metadata in a supported way. At present I have an attribute which I dont want to show in advanced find view.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The following link contains all you need to know about making an attribute none – searchable
http://mscrmtools.wordpress.com/tools/searchable-property-attribute-updater/

Comment: I do not want it to be visible in advanced find at all.. even in add view columns. Can you please help!

Comment: Searchable and presentable are to different aspects. There’s no attribute related "if adv find or else" feature in this product.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to update IsValidForAdvancedFind attribute but not every attribute of any entity can be updated. Can you please share which attribute from which entity do you want to update?